# why net use delete command returns question mark

Tags: windows, filemaker

A filemaker script calls 'net use delete x:' command, but the return value is '?'. 
does anyone knows what does that mean?

Comment: This does not look like a FileMaker script step. Post more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are using "Send Event" to run "net use delete". This is more about cmd usage than FileMaker. This command should disconnect you from a shared resource on the network. '?' could mean an error which Filemaker does not recognise. If it does what it should, I would ignore it. If it does not you have to check if you are connected to the resource and if network resource is called with the correct name when you disconnect. Also check the permissions. The best way to debug it is to make sure you can run the same commands in cmd.